# Recorrer Registros comparando horas SQL

Tags: sql-server-2019

tengo la siguiente tabla de logs que envia un rastreador de actividad cada minuto:

```
//Tabla Logs
Emp Time
621 2023-12-20 12:40:31.990
621 2023-12-20 12:42:32.063
621 2023-12-20 13:37:09.933
621 2023-12-20 13:41:09.967
```

de la cual quiero obtener algo como esto en otra tabla donde se registren los periodos de actividad continuos (si hay una diferencia mayor a 5 min de un log a otro se crea un nuevo registro):

```
//Tabla Activities
Emp Started                 Ended
621 2023-12-20 12:40:31.990 2023-12-20 12:42:32.063
621 2023-12-20 13:37:09.933 2023-12-20 13:41:09.967
```

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahorita:

```
DECLARE @Emp int, @TIME DateTime;
DECLARE @prev DateTime, @start DateTime, @end DateTime;
DECLARE log_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT Emp,Time FROM Tracker_Check  GROUP BY EMP, TIME ORDER BY TIME;

OPEN log_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM log_cursor INTO @Emp, @Time;
SET @prev= @TIME
SET @start=@TIME
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
        IF(@TIME >=DATEADD(minute,5,@prev))
        BEGIN
            //de momento solo lo imprimo para ver la salida
            PRINT CONCAT(@Emp,' ','Started:',@start,' - Ended:',@prev)
            SET @start=@TIME
            SET @prev=@Time
        END
        SET @prev=@Time
        FETCH NEXT FROM log_cursor INTO @Emp, @Time;
    END
Close log_cursor;
DEALLOCATE log_cursor;
```

pero solo obtengo la siguiente salida:

```
621 Started:Dec 20 2023 12:40PM - Ended:2023-12-20 12:42:32.063
```

No se genera el ultimo registro no logro encontar lo que estoy haciendo mal, seguramente en el ciclo WHILE

esto para poder programar un job en SQL-Agent que haga el insert en la tabla Activities y limpie la tabla logs cada dia.

PD, actualmente lo hago con C# recorriendo la tabla con un loop foreach(), pero quiero ver si hay forma de hacerlo desde un procedimiento almacenado.
PD2 El motor de base de datos es SQL Server v15.0.2000.5

Comment: y para eso, existen las etiquetas...  ;)...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!